# php не может определить ключи массива

Tags: php, массивы

при создании объекта класса передается массив параметров, и если при создании одного объекта все работает как надо, то при создании другого php ведет себя странно

```
var_dump($attr);
echo('<br><br>');
var_dump(array_keys($attr));
```

из кода выше я получаю это:

```
aray(1){[0]=>array(4){["id"]=>string(1)"1"["access_level"]=>string(45)"администрирование сайта"["name"]=>string(26)=>"Администратор"["role"]=>string(5)"admin"}}
array(1){[0]=>int(0)}
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Ну у тебя `$attr` содержит массив где нулевой элемент тоже массив с ключами `id`, `access_level`, ...

Видимо ты имел ввиду `array_keys($attr[0])` ?

Comment: Там ведь в дампе понятным языком написано  array(1) { (0 й элемент) =>  array(4)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо комментариям от Eugene X.
На самом деле глупая ошибка, нужно было использовать `array_keys($attr[0])`